# Sample from bernoulli distribution using 1 bit of entropy

Tags: information-theory, bernoulli-distribution

Given 1 bit of entropy (eg the outcome of flipping a fair coin), is it possible to generate a sample from a bernoulli distribution with $p \neq 0.5$? Intuitively it seems like it should be possible - a bernoulli distribution with $p \neq 0.5$ has less than 1 bit of entropy. But I can't think of how. If this is impossible, why?

Comment: @Sycorax it seems like that's the opposite problem - they're using a biased coin to generate a uniform distribution. Here I want to use a single flip of a fair coin to generate a (biased) bernoulli distribution. I can't think of how to apply the techniques suggested in that post to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to generate a single sample from a bernoulli of arbitrary $p$ given a single fair coin flip. Suppose you had some rule $f: \text{Bool} \rightarrow \text{Bool}$ which did map coin flip result to True/False. It's easy to see there are only 4 mappings, 2 of which sample from bernoulli with $p = 0.5$ and the other two sample from $p = 0$ and $p = 1$ respectively. So this is a proof by exhaustion.

Also note that with $n$ coin flips there are only $2^n$ possible results, so you can't sample from any bernoulli with $p$ not a multiple of $2^{-n}$ even in that case.

> If this is impossible, why?

I would be a bit careful with interpreting results from information theory. Just because one thing has more entropy than another doesn't mean you can use the former to sample from the latter.